# state could not be resolved in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using nested view for ui-router. 
My menu html

```
<li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('staffs')}">
                <a ui-sref="dashboard"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span class="nav-label">{{ 'STAFFS' | translate }}</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse" ng-class="{in: $state.includes('staffs')}">
                    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="staffs.add"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>{{ 'ADDSTAFF' | translate }}</a></li>
                    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="staffs.view"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>{{ 'VIEWSTAFFS' | translate }}</a></li>
                    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="staffs.permission"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>{{ 'STAFFPERMISSION' | translate }}</a></li>
                    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="staffs.prdtype"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>{{ 'PRODUCTTYPE' | translate }}</a></li>  
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Below is my config.js

```js
.state('staffs.add', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/add_staff",
            templateUrl: "views/staff_add.php",
        })
```

I am getting an error Error: Could not resolve 'staffs.add' from state ''.
Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong

Comment: is this a typo or do you really have a link `staffs.add` trying to reach a state `staffs.addstaffs`?  The link and the state should be the same.

Comment: I am sorry for the wrong question. I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot go to an `abstract` state, `abstract` state can act as container/parent state

remove `abstract: true`, it should work

I'm not sure how `.php` files are usable as angular template

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the name of state try this

```
 <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="staffs.addstaffs"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>{{ 'ADDSTAFF' | translate }}</a></li>
```